# Does virtually-LERF imply LERF?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, finitely-generated, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group.

Recall that a group $L$ is LERF if every finitely generated subgroup $H$ of $G$ is equal to the intersection of the finite index subgroups of $G$ which contain $H$ (i.e. every finitely generated subgroup is profinitely closed).

Assume that $G$ is virtually LERF. That is, there is a finite index subgroup $L$ of $G$ which is LERF. Does this imply that $G$ is LERF?
(this is indeed the situation with residually finite groups, but I don't know whether this extends to LERF groups)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, and it's easy.

Let $H$ be a f.g. subgroup of $G$. so $H\cap L$ is intersection of finite index subgroups of $L$ and hence of $G$; that is, $H\cap L$ is closed in the profinite topology. Being a finite union of cosets of $H\cap L$, $H$ is closed as well.